# Unknown animated movie with a powerful glove

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

When I was a child I watched an animated movie on VHS, whether it has multiple series or a TV show, I cannot remember, but I have been looking for it ever since.(Its only been 15 years.)

The general plot involves a boy looking for his father. The movie starts with a chase seen with bright beams of light and these creepy goons with trench coats and hats are chasing a man. One of them catches him and the man uses a glove with a circle in the middle to defend (kinda like iron man, but no obvious tech, just a grey glove with a darker circle.

I remember that after the intro (above), the story continues with the mans son. An associate of his dad gives him the glove (important scene when he teaches him to use it and slices a small tree with it)(associate may have been black?)
Then the search for his dad starts. I have been googling this for so long and I can't even narrow it down.

There's a motorcycle he uses (that's unlocked by the glove) that also doubles as a hovercycle. In terms of plot I can only remember hes looking for his dad.(Who is part of a secret society and the glove is a key for a bunch of stuff like a base high tech base of some kind)

Random other things I remember:

- I don't think it was an anime, rather animated in an american style (like batman beyond?)(I tried researching animators too)
- The main guy may or may not leave the planet (there's a weird scene where a young boy chants "Get him" over and over) (His dad or the creepy kid may have an eyepatch?)

I remember it so clearly but I can't find anything! (The glove and motorcycle I thought would be main points to search)

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to M&TV. Please add only required information. You'll get answers here. Nice question by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Invasion America](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0161718/combined), an animated miniseries from 1998.

> A young crossbreed human and alien fights to keep both of his worlds from going to war. His father, an alien (Tyrusian) emperor and his mother, a human, are both missing, and the young man (David) has to discover who his friends and enemies really are.

The glove was called Exotar. All the other things you've mentioned (the hovering bike, his father having an eyepatch etc.) are there. You can find the first scene you described in the beginning of this clip:

Comment: OH MY GOD. THANK YOU!!! I have been looking for so long, I can't wait to watch it again ! I am forever grateful.